# Qual a Definição de NULL em C?

Tags: c, null

eai, estava estudando com meu amigo, e a gente está quebrando a cabeça pois não sabemos o que exatamente é a função NULL! Pois em cada programa que vemos, o NULL pode servir de outra forma, vou colocar uma programa aqui como exemplo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
 char str1[21], str2[21];
 printf("Digite duas palavras: ");
 scanf(" %20[^\n] %20[^\n]", str1, str2);
 if (strstr(str1, str2) != NULL) {
 printf("%s ocorre em %s\n", str2, str1);
 }
 else {
 printf("%s NAO ocorre em %s\n", str2, str1);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Se `(strstr(str1,str2)) != NULL`? Eu não entendi essa Parte, como assim?

Comment: O título da sua pergunta não condiz com sua dúvida no último parágrafo. A função `strstr` retorna o ponteiro de onde encontrar a substring na string maior, e na ausência retorna `NULL`

Answer (score 3):

Boa tarde, na liguagem **C** o valor **NULL** server para indicar que o **ponteiro** não está apontando para um valor na memoria.

> Digamos que o primeiro array de char, **str1**, é igual a "gato cachorro comida"
>   e o segundo array de char, **str2**, é "cachorro", qual o resultado da função **strstr** ?

```
char str1[21] = "gato cachorro comida";
char str2[21] = "cachorro";

char[21] resultado = strstr(str1,str2);
```

> O resultado sera o array de char **"cachorro comida"**, a funcao **strstr** procurou pela primeira ocorrência de **str2**, em **str1** e achou a ocorrencia resultando no array de char "cachorro comida"".
>  *Então se a função não achasse a ocorrencia ela retornaria o valor **NULL***
> No seu caso vc está testando se existe a ocorrência **str2** em **str1** através da expressão abaixo:

```
if (strstr(str1,str2) != NULL) {
     //Executa este bloco de código se a ocorrência EXISTIR
}
else {
     //Executa este bloco de código se a ocorrência NÃO EXISTIR
}
```

Espero que tenha entendido!
Caso queira dominar mais o assunto procure estudar **Ponteiros** na linguagem C